E: Репозиторий «http://zabbix.repo.timeweb.ru/debian bookworm Release» не содержит файла Release
Не сильно разбираюсь в линуксе, но очень нужно поставить кое-что на удаленный сервер, но при попытке прописать sudo apt-get update, вывод в консоль такой:
Игн:1 http://zabbix.repo.timeweb.ru/debian bookworm InRelease
Ошб:2 http://zabbix.repo.timeweb.ru/debian bookworm Release                                   
  404  Not Found [IP: **ipipipip** 80]
Сущ:3 http://repo.fastpanel.direct bookworm InRelease                                         
Сущ:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease                  
Сущ:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease                                         
Сущ:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
E: Репозиторий «http://zabbix.repo.timeweb.ru/debian bookworm Release» не содержит файла Release.
N: Обновление из этого репозитория нельзя выполнить безопасным способом, поэтому по умолчанию он отключён.
N: Информацию о создании репозитория и настройках пользователя смотрите в справочной странице apt-secure(8).


нету тут bookworm: http://zabbix.repo.timeweb.ru/debian/dists/ // откуда вы его взяли?

Сервер новый или старый обновлялся с какой-то предыдущей версии дебиана?

@andreymal, сервер, насколько я знаю, новый и не обновлялся

Заказал в таймвебе новый облачный сервер на bookworm — в файле прописано bullseye как положено, значит это на вашем сервере чьи-то шаловливые ручки специально залезли в этот файл и сломали его
